# Nonsingularity and inverse of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having some trouble solving this question:

Let $A,B,C,D$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose $C$ and $A-BC^{-1}B^T$  are nonsingular.

Show that the matrix mentioned is nonsingular and find its inverse
\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B^T&C\end{bmatrix}

For nonsingularity $\det(M)$ is not $0$.

Any help is appreciated :)

Edit:

I found that M is nonsingular, can anyone help me finding the inverse?

Comment: Determinant of block matrices necessarily don't follow the rules of matrices with numerical entries

Comment: are the matrices $A$ and $C$ symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B^T & C
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
U & V \\
W & X
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
AU+BW & AV+BX \\
B^TU+CW & B^TV+CX \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So we want

- $B^TU+CW=0$, hence $W=-C^{-1}B^TU$
- $AU+BW=I$, so $AU-BC^{-1}B^TU=I$ and therefore $U=(A-BC^{-1}B^T)^{-1}$

Similarly for $V$ and $X$:

- $B^TV+CX=I$, so $X=C^{-1}(I-B^TV)$
- $AV+BX=0$, so $AV+BC^{-1}(I-B^TV)=0$, so
  $$
  AV+BC^{-1}-BC^{-1}BTV=0
  $$
  and $V=-(A-BC^{-1}B^T)BC^{-1}$

You can compute $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A, B, C$, and $D$ are matrices of dimension $n × n$, $n × m$, $m × n$, and $m × m$, respectively.
In general, when $D$ is invertible, a similar identity with ${\displaystyle \det(D)}$  factored out can be derived:

$${\displaystyle \det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C).}$$

See more on the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how to show ${\displaystyle \det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C).}$ is true?

Comment: I see it now :)